# set :deploy_via, :remote_cache this option is not applied to submodules

Tags: capistrano

I am using git submodule feature with capistrano. I have

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :git_enable_submodules,1
```

Everything works great. However remote_cache option is only applied to main app. Which means that every single time I deploy the app all submodules pull in all changes and that takes a lot of time.

Is there a way to tell submodule to use :remote_cache.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to go deep into [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) sources, just search for **git_enable_submodules** and **remote_cache**.

I think there is no suitable to be used with remote_cache, but that should be no problem as you can copy code that does git_enable_submodules and write your own implementation.

When You have your solution you can fork capistrano add it to code and ask for pull request.